# Adding onKeyPress to existing <a onClick={}></a>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been attempting to add several onKeyPress to existing onClick  tags in my React.js project, more specifically, being able to press Enter to fire off an onClick after tabbing to a link.  The onKeyPress in my code works properly when I insert a simple console.log() to test, however it fails when I insert the function.  I left out irrelevant portions of code for brevity. Essentially I need click and Enter to do the same thing. Thanks!!!

```
class Link extends React.Component {

    changeSection(e) {
        // code to change section
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <a id="menu-item" tabIndex={this.props.tabIndex} onKeyPress={(e) => {(e.key === 'Enter' ? this.changeSection.bind(this) : null)}} onClick={this.changeSection.bind(this)}>
                    {this.props.linkText}
                </a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the _it fails_ part please.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to let the browser handle it for you, especially because you're already using an `a` tag. It might not be nice to add the `href="#"`, but it's probably better than a function that is regenerated every render. Plus you don't have the overhead with the custom tabbing implementation.

Try it here:

```js
class Link extends React.Component {
  changeSection(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Fired!');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a
          id="menu-item"
          href="#"
          onClick={this.changeSection.bind(this)}
        >
          {this.props.linkText}
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Link linkText="Test" />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a syntax error. Does this work? If not, what error are you getting?

```
<a id="menu-item" tabIndex={this.props.tabIndex} onKeyPress={(e) => (e.key === 'Enter') ? this.changeSection.bind(this) : null} onClick={this.changeSection.bind(this)}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed 2 syntax together I think.

You can change this;

```
onKeyPress={(e) => {(e.key === 'Enter' ? this.changeSection.bind(this) : null)}}
```

With this;

```
onKeyPress={(e) => { 
    if(e.key === 'Enter') this.changeSection.bind(this);
    else null
}}
```

or with this;

```
onKeyPress={(e) => (e.key === 'Enter' ? this.changeSection.bind(this) : null)}
```

Answer (score -1):

`onKeyPress={(e) => {(e.key === 'Enter' ? this.changeSection.bind(this) : null)}}`

I think this is where you fail. Your code here just binds new context to a function but doesn't call it.